# How to get the real file type for images that do not have an extension

Tags: images, uploads

So i have a front end form that let users upload images from an URL...

Everything its ok when the image URL have the proper extension like this:

http://mydomain.com/image.jpg

but when the image url doesn't have an extension like this :

http://mydomain.com/image

My code doesn't work.

This is how i get the extension:

```
$filetype = wp_check_filetype($imageurl, null);
```

Now, if the file name of the image retrieved does have an extension, say jpg, then the output of the above call is

```
Array
(
    [ext] => jpg
    [type] => image/jpeg
)
```

However if the extension is not part of the file name then the call above returns the following array

```
Array
(
    [ext] =>
    [type] =>
)
```

How can i get the real file type for images that do not have an extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you can not exactly determine, but you can assume one with header data.

```
$headers = wp_get_http_headers( $url );
$mime_type = $headers['content-type'];
$ext = '';
foreach ( wp_get_mime_types() as $exts => $mime ) {
    if ( $mime == $mime_type ) {
        $ext = $exts;
        break;
    }
}
```

Now in the `$ext` variable, it could be multiple extensions that have been matched, and there's no way to determine which one the image actually have. But, you could try the first one.

```
if( $ext ){
    $exts = explode('|', $ext);
    $ext = $exts[0];
}
```